# flex 4 default channel set ignored

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

When u start a  new project, the default configuration is to use my-amf channel for all destinations like this:

```
<default-channels>
    <channel ref="my-amf"/>
</default-channels>
```

But suddenly, something got screw up and i have to specify an end point for every remote object in the project, because if i don't, every remote object but one (idk why this works...) will fail with the error message:

Destination 'name' not accessible over channel 'my-rtmp'

I was told that my project name being different to the context root in flex server properties could be the cause, but this is not the case.

Any ideas of what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this was a little disappointing, i just found out, some routes on the build path and and even the flex compiler arguments were messed up...

This should be the first place i had look at, but with all the rush, i wasn't thinking clearly, its all good now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the default values for your destination in the web config. Change that to whatever your CF server is set up to use.

Comment: There is a <default-channels> tag with "my-rtmp" as the default value but in the services-config.xml, nothing abut destinations in the web config. I already tried changing that one to "my-amf" but still getting the same error =/

Comment: What server tech are you using?

Comment: JBoss 7.1.1 Final deploying as a war.

Comment: sorry, Ive not used Jboss :(